# leftMap on a ValidationNel

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is there an existing combinator in scalaz or a better way ?

```
def leftMapNel[E, EE, A](v: ValidationNel[E, A])(f: E => EE) : ValidationNel[EE, A] =
  v.leftMap(_.map(f))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`ValidationNel[E, A]` is just a shorthand for `Validation[NonEmptyList[E], A]` (as you can [see in the code](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/abbd0238972d71bd07724218d4f85341ab720389/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L209)) and it does not provide any specific function to handle the `NonEmptyList`.

Comment: In this case the "No" part is true (I think?), but it doesn't really follow from the fact that `ValidationNel` is a type alias. There are lots of `ValidationNel`-specific helper methods in Scalaz even though it's "just shorthand", and I don't think it'd be unreasonable to have a `leftMapNel` like this on `Validation` (with the appropriate implicit evidence parameters, etc.).

Comment: @TravisBrown Do you think it worth a PR ?

Comment: @YannMoisan To be honest probably not—my "not unreasonable" might be very slightly overstated, since it's easy to do this manually and the evidence stuff would be cumbersome—but I'm not very involved in Scalaz development, so who knows.

Comment: @TravisBrown I've finally made a PR, nice discussion : https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/1081